# Who selects the General Secretary of Indian National Congress or Bhartiya Janata Party?

Tags: constitution, india, indian-national-congress, bjp

What is the process to select the general secretary of the party?
Does one have to be a publicly elected official to hold this post?
Are there any regulations in Indian Constitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The General Secretaries of the INC are the organisational executives of the All India Congress Committee, and are selected by the President of the Indian National Congress.  The President is elected by an electoral college composed of members of the AICC and State level Pradesh Congress Committees.

The General Secretary of the BJP is appointed by the President of the BJP

There is no requirement for these roles to be held by elected politicians.  The internal structures of the political parties is not a matter for the National Constitution (save some broad principles, such a having a "leader" to become Prime Minister if the party is wins the Lok Sabah elections)